# Firewall init script

Tags: iptables

On Debian, what is the best way to start an iptables firewall script :

1. /etc/init.d/firewall_script.sh
2. in /etc/network/interfaces, add post-up /etc/network/if-up.d/firewall_script.sh

Do you check if the firewall is active and restart it if it's not the case ? if yes, how ?

Thanks for advices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the iptables-persistent package:

https://packages.debian.org/stable/admin/iptables-persistent

This manages iptables persistence by saving rules in the file /etc/iptables/rules.v4 for IPv4 and /etc/iptables/rules.v6 for IPv6

A good source if information for this is here => http://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Saving_Iptables_Firewall_Rules_Permanently

Answer (score 0):

I think of preferences let each service instance that launches separately from each other 'Networking and iptables , so after the network service start the script statements will also launch .

1. /etc/init.d/firewall_script.sh

Answer (score 0):

I use the post-up line in the interfaces file (like your option 2) except not in the if-up.d directory.  I think putting it there that would make it be invoked twice.  To check on the firewall I use 
    **iptables -vnL | less**